# Moving a sub folder/ area path in tfs 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-migration

One of my team's created a new folder under a team project and using it as a separate project in tfs 2015.

Is it possible to move that sub folder project to a new project in the same collection?.

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [tf rename command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/rename-command-team-foundation-version-control) to move the path of a file or folder without losing the source control history.

```
tf rename "$/PROJECT/Sub folder/*.*" "$/NEW PROJECT/XX/"
```

> *Note: The results of this command **are not reflected** in the Team Foundation version control server until you perform a check-in
>   operation.*
>
> **Required Permissions**
>
> To use the rename command, you have the **Check out** permission set to
>   **Allow**.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but the folder has three different sub folders in it. Can I move the folder to new team project with in the same collection without having any effect on Work items ?.

Comment: My pleasure ,any update on it? In your situation, the 'move' is not accurate. But you can copy it to another project in the same collection using the copy option in Web Access (manually). This actually just creates a new work item and copies all the matching field values to the new item. If it works, could you mark it as an answer? If it's not working, glad to give your more advise.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your help, haven't tried it yet was busy administering TFS as of now. Will update you once I get a chance to change the folders.